# ngif Hiding div content

Tags: java, angular

I have two divs

```
<div1 ngif (condition)>
   html tags

</div>
<div2>
    html tags
</div>
```

I want to show the first div basing on the condition. But there is no condition for second div. So If I hide the first div second div should take its place. Can anyone help me here.

Comment: And this is why proper code formatting is not optional on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
<div1 ngIf="condition">
   html tags

</div>
<div2 [class.enlarged]="!condition>
    html tags
</div>
```

Comment: There is no condition for second div.  second div should be visible. So if my first div is hidden , second div should occupy its space. But thanks a lot for your prompt reply.

Comment: "So if my first div is hidden , second div should occupy its space.". That's the default behavior anyway. What's the problem?

Comment: Problem is there is space and second div has gone down.

Comment: See my updated answer. You can fix it in CSS to make the 2nd div bigger when the `condition` is false.

Comment: Thanks , that should be it :)